# multiple known object detection and tracking in opencv

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing, tracking

I am using a microscope to observe the motion of small 4 micron beads.  I have a video of the beads moving and I would like to process the video to extract the bead locations as a function of time to get a mathematical model of their motion.

I am currently using opencv and programming in python

My code was importing a video from file, thresholding the image then applying a HoughCircles transform to find the spherical beads.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def nothing(x):
    pass

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('testvideo.mp4')
cv2.namedWindow('trackbar')

cv2.createTrackbar('Param1','trackbar',40,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('Param2','trackbar',10,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('MaxRadius','trackbar',18,255,nothing)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    e1 = cv2.getTickCount()
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    #get grayscale image for HoughCircles
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    p1 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Param1','trackbar')
    p2 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Param2','trackbar')
    rMax = cv2.getTrackbarPos('MaxRadius','trackbar')    

    #Threshold grayscale image    
    ret,th1 = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    #Find circles in image and store locations to circles list
    circles =  cv2.HoughCircles(th1, cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 10, 
                                param1=p1, param2=p2,minRadius=0,
                                maxRadius=rMax)    
    #Hack for fixing the list if it is empty so program wont crash
    if circles == None:
        circles = [[[0,0,0.000],[0,0,0.000]]] 

    #convert circles list to integer list    
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

    #store points to a file
    datafile = file('datafile.txt', 'a')
    np.savetxt(datafile, circles[0], fmt ='%i',delimiter=',', newline = ',')
    datafile.write('\n')
    datafile.close()    

    for i in circles[0,:]:
        # draw the outer circle
        cv2.circle(frame,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
        # draw the center of the circle
        cv2.circle(frame,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
        cv2.imshow('detected circles',frame)
        cv2.imshow('threshold video',th1) 

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

    e2 = cv2.getTickCount()
    time = (e2 - e1)/ cv2.getTickFrequency()
    print time

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is a sample frame from the video I am using for detecting the beads.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS8Dg.jpg

Here is an example of the single frame tracking that I did with the previous algorithm
https://i.stack.imgur.com/izvuz.jpg

I don't need to detect every single bead.  Just an aggregate would be fine.

The beads are spherical and should look the same, so is there a library that I can use to integrate the bead image over the entire image and see where the points are most correlated in the image?  Sometimes the beads are out of focus and that's why the current program I have keeps bouncing around and giving me false positives for the beads.

I eventually need this process to happen realtime so if possible it would be nice to have the algorithm be as efficient as possible.

If anyone knows a good approach to this type of problem it would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the beads contrained on the Z-axis (or to put another way, would their size be pretty much constant).  They look it from the sample image which would make me want to also be able to specify a minRadius greater than zero. Also, are you trying to follow individual beads around (or just count the # of beads or calculate centers of mass); that might impact which algorithm to suggest

Comment: I am trying to extract the motion of the beads in the xy plane.  The beads are in a solution of water and are for the most part on laying flat on the xy plane.  The size of the beads is constant but sometimes they would clump together, in which case I would have to look at individual beads in the cluster and not look at the cluster as one entity.  The purpose is to calculate velocity and temperature of the beads in the solution.  I would like to follow many beads in the solution and extract their x,y coordinates.  The more the better.

Comment: Could you share a small portion of the video (not just a single frame)? This would help to get a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Did you try your video with the motempl example?  That would seem (at least to this sleep-deprived foon) to come close to what you're looking for (possibly tweaking some of the parameters); if the beads clump, you might need to modify things (by e.g. looking for when the size returned exceeds your radius and doing a sub-scan of those areas, though it would seem like the treating the clump as an average might be acceptable); as Tomas pointed out, a few frames might help understand things a bit